# ReactJS: Render data in two columns

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactstrap

I have this Component:

```
export const RenderDetail = props => {
  const createRows = props.content.reduce(function (rows, key, index) {
    console.log('rows, key, index', rows, key, index);
    return (index % 2 === 0 ? rows.push([key]) : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)) && rows;
  }, []);

 return (
    <div>
      {createRows.map((row, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={`item_${index}`}>
            <Row>
              {row.map((col, key) => {
                return (
                  console.log('col ', col),
                  (
                    <div key={`item_${key}`} style={{ margin: '20px' }}>
                      <Col>
                        <dl className="jh-entity-details">
                          <dt>
                            <span id={col.id}>{col.name}</span>
                          </dt>
                          <dd>{col.value}</dd>
                        </dl>
                      </Col>
                    </div>
                  )
                );
              })}
            </Row>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I pass to this component an array of Object like:

```
const Container = [
{
 id: "id",
 name: "ID",
 value: "10"
},
]
```

**What I would to obtain:**

I wanted to get the data divided into two columns, but in this way they are too close and stuck together. Is there a way to represent them so that they take up the whole page (always in two columns?)

EDIT:

Using `<Col xs="12" md="6">` as suggested

[image: Image2]

Comment: can you add a sandbox? do you use `reactstrap`?

Comment: Yes I use reactstrap, I have created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-elgamal-57cog?file=/src/index.js:186-193

(but maybe some problem with the index.js)

Comment: @Jack23 Use <Col xs="12" md="6"> for your cols

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev I have tried your solution, but it doens't work good. ( i post a new picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered your sandbox. Check the new one

The problem was at this part of code

```
                <div key={`item_${key}`} style={{ margin: '20px' }}>
                  <Col>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-grass-3jp76)

First of all i removed the `div` that enclosed the `Col` tag and then set the 6-grid attribute to become of 50% width.